# Appending only a subset of a dataframe with another one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For two dataframes like

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,5,6] , 'B' : [3,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,7,6] , 'B' : [31,81,91]})
```

how could we append (or other combining technique) `df2` to `df1` but consider only those rows of `df2` which have common `A` with `df1`? and get

```
pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,5,6,1,6], 'B' : [3,8,9,31,91]})
```

and how could we consider only those rows of `df2` which don't have common `A` with `df1`? and get

```
pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,5,6,7], 'B' : [3,8,9,81]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to find the common values and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to join the DataFrames:

```
mask = df2['A'].isin(df1['A'])
intersection = pd.concat((df1, df2[mask]))
print(intersection)
```

**Output** *(intersection)*

```
   A   B
0  1   3
1  5   8
2  6   9
0  1  31
2  6  91
```

Now the second part, use the negation of the mask:

```
mask = df2['A'].isin(df1['A'])
difference = pd.concat((df1, df2[~mask]))
print(difference)
```

**Output** *(difference)*

```
   A   B
0  1   3
1  5   8
2  6   9
1  7  81
```